# Place text based divs in relative locations within a circle

Tags: javascript, html, kml, google-earth

Direct question - How would I place certain objects or small text within a certain area.  For example, how would I replace the following image with html/javascript.

--- I don't have enough reps to post an image :/ but try this URL - https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3eWL.jpg

Big picture - I am trying to create a kml file for Google Earth that when the point is clicked, the balloon description window pops up and I can display my html formatted diagram showing where the satellites are at that instant.  Google Earth and KML docs allow for pretty much any html formatting within it, so currently looking for a good way to do this.

Disclaimer: It has been a few years since i have done any html or javascript editing, so general examples and insight is greatful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the below section is what I did.

```
<div style="display: block; position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; background: gray;">
    <div style="position:absolute; width: 296px;height: 296px;background-color: transparent;border: 2px #a72525 solid;   -webkit-border-radius: 148px;   border-radius: 148px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; width: 148px;height: 148px;top: 72px;left: 72px;background-color: transparent;border: 2px #a72525 solid; -webkit-border-radius: 75px;border-radius: 75px;"></div>  
    <div style="position:absolute;  width: 4px;   height: 4px;top:148px;    left:148px;    background-color: black;"></div>  
    <div style="position: absolute; font-size: 0.8em; color: #222222; top: %dpx; left: %dpx;">%d</div>    
</div>
```

The last div are the labels that are placed wherever.  The %d are integer values (from my python code)

In addition, here is the working example.  Props to nico
http://jsfiddle.net/94Kzt/72/

Comment: Sorry, I only saw your comments now, but I am glad you managed to make it work anyways!

Answer (score 1):

You can just create some absolute positioned `<div>`s that you move with their `top` and `left` CSS properties.

A quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/94Kzt/ (note: I used JQuery to do it quickly, but it is easy to modify it to use standard JS DOM manipulation calls)

Comment: That was pretty neat.  Could you help me tweak some of my code there.  I am trying to center everything (except the label of course) and am getting confused on how the position tag works and how to place teh div tags and if they should be contained in one another or not.  http://jsfiddle.net/94Kzt/51/

Comment: This part of the code seemed to work, although not sure why it is not offset like the above -51 rev. http://jsfiddle.net/94Kzt/35/

Comment: See my response for my answer.  Sorry, I don't have enough rep to vote you up.